# How to relocate the database directory for Red Hat Directory Server 9.0

Tags: redhat, 389-ds, directory-services, slapd

I am running RHDS in a VM, but would like to store the data and logs on a separate volume, that is on a SAN.  The partition is ext4fs on /sdb1 and is mounted as /data.

I tried many variations of the different approaches described here.  First, after a fresh install of RHDS, before I created any instances, I created the folders on /data and linked to them from /var, as follows:

```
mkdir /data/lib
mkdir /data/log
mkdir /data/lib/dirsrv
mkdir /data/log/dirsrv
rmdir /var/log/dirsrv
rmdir /var/lib/dirsrv
ln -s /data/lib/dirsrv/ /var/lib/
ln -s /data/log/dirsrv/ /var/log/
```

When I create an instance (named esx02vm01) of the directory, I get this error:

```
[02/May/2013:09:51:45 -0400] - /etc/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01/dse.ldif:
nsslapd-errorlog: Cannot open errorlog file
"/var/log/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01/errors",
errors cannot be logged.  Exiting....
```

I thought RHDS might be having trouble with the symbolic links.  In my second attempt, I instantiated with files in the default locations.  After confirming the directory was working, I shut it down.  Then I moved the instance folders under /var/lib and /var/log over to the /data folder and modified the dse.ldif file for that instance to point to the new folder locations, as follows:

```
mkdir /data/lib
mkdir /data/log
mkdir /data/lib/dirsrv
mkdir /data/log/dirsrv
cp -r --preserve=all /var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01 /data/lib/dirsrv/
cp -r --preserve=all /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01 /data/log/dirsrv/
vi /etc/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01/dse.ldif
* replace all /var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01 with /data/lib/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01*
:%s/\/var\/lib\/dirsrv\/slapd-esx02vm01\//\/data\/lib\/dirsrv\/slapd-esx02vm01\//g
* (6 substitutions on 6 lines)
* replace all /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01 with /data/log/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01
:%s/\/var\/log\/dirsrv\/slapd-esx02vm01\//\/data\/log\/dirsrv\/slapd-esx02vm01\//g
* (4 substitutions on 4 lines)
:qw
mv /var/lib/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01 /var/lib/dirsrv/old-slapd-esx02vm01
mv /var/log/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01 /var/log/dirsrv/old-slapd-esx02vm01
service dirsrv start
```

I got the same error attempting to start the directory:

```
Starting dirsrv:
esx02vm01...[03/May/2013:08:56:00 -0400] - /etc/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01/dse.ldif:
nsslapd-errorlog: Cannot open errorlog file
"/data/log/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01/errors",
errors cannot be logged.  Exiting....
```

Then, I moved the error file back to the original location, so just the database file was on /data.  These errors where logged when the directory is started:

```
[03/May/2013:09:17:17 -0400] - 389-Directory/1.2.11.15 B2013.100.2247 starting up
[03/May/2013:09:17:17 -0400] - mkdir_p : error -5950 (File not found.)
[03/May/2013:09:17:17 -0400] - Can't start because the database directory
"/data/lib/dirsrv/slapd-esx02vm01/db" either doesn't exist, or is not accessible
[03/May/2013:09:17:17 -0400] - start: Failed to init database, err=-1 Unknown error: -1
```

In each case, I confirmed that the reported directories and files exist, and that they have the same ownership and permissions as the original directories and files.  When I created the instance, I ran setup-ds-admin.pl as root, using the account rhds for the instance.  I created the rhds user with the command:

```
useradd -M rhds
```

What is the proper way to relocate the databases for an instance of Red Hat Directory Server?

-Luke

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure works successfully for me with 389-ds 1.2.9.14:

1. create a new instance
2. make sure dirsrv is stopped: `service dirsrv stop`
3. move the `/var/lib/dirsrv/` directory to the data partition; in my case `/mnt/389ds/data/`
4. create a symbolic link from `/var/lib/dirsrv/` to `/mnt/389ds/data/`
5. move the `/var/log/dirsrv/` directory to the data partition; in my case `/mnt/389ds/log/`
6. create a symbolic link from `/var/log/dirsrv/` to `/mnt/389ds/log/`
7. start the server: `service dirsrv start`

I have installed multiple production servers this way and they are all running well!